# How to send logs to table so that we can view them in Workbench?

Tags: mysql, logging, mysql-workbench

At log tab, it shows :

> Your current Log Destination is set to FILE.
>   For logs to be viewed within Workbench they must be configured to be sent to TABLE.
>   This option is only available in MySQL version 5.1 and newer.
>   Fore more information read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/log­tables.html

I am new to MYSQL and currently work with Workbench. I need to view query logs. Can you please show me step by step clearly how to make the log tab show query logs?

Thanks

Comment: Hey, then again, if they are currently logging to FILE, you can just download the file from the server and view the logs there. But I am guessing you want to see the logs in Workbench, and workbench can only work with tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When administering your server in Workbench, go to the Options File page under CONFIGURATION. Then go to the Log Files tab. There are several options you can configure there to enable the logs. The one related with logging to tables is called log-output (shown under "Advanced log options"). You have to set it to TABLE. Then enable the logs you require:

- The general log (logs all queries made to the DB), under "Activate Logging" (make sure it's checked).
- The slow log (logs all queries that have taken more time to complete than some threshold you set), under "Slow query log options" (check the option slow-query-log and set the threshold in seconds in the longquerytime field).

Remember to click on the Apply button after finishing your changes and restart the server to make it reload the new settings.

Keep in mind that the error log cannot be logged in tables. The upcoming version of Workbench (5.2.36) will have support for log files too.

Comment: Thanks, it works. However, can I make it run as real time log ? (doesn't require to refresh in order to see new logs). And is there a way to eliminate "SELECT count(*) AS count FROM mysql.general_log" ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you should start the MySQL server with a special parameter or edit the configuration file, but you can also change this on a running server. Don't forget to set the variable in the configuration file afterwards so the setting remains after a server restart.

From [MySQL Documentation: Log-destinations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/log-destinations.html)

> Log control at runtime. Several system variables are associated with
>   log tables and files and enable runtime control over logging:
>
> The global log_output system variable indicates the current logging
>   destination. It can be modified at runtime to change the destination.
>
> The global general_log and slow_query_log variables indicate whether
>   the general query log and slow query log are enabled (ON) or disabled
>   (OFF). You can set these variables at runtime to control whether the
>   logs are enabled.
>
> The global general_log_file and slow_query_log_file variables
>   indicate the names of the general query log and slow query log files.
>   As of MySQL 5.1.29, you can set these variables at server startup or
>   at runtime to change the names of the log files. Before MySQL 5.1.29,
>   you can set these variables only at runtime, but the --log and
>   --log-slow-queries options can be given with a file name argument at startup to change the log file names from their default values.
>
> The session sql_log_off variable can be set to ON or OFF to disable
>   or enable general query logging for the current connection.

So typically you would want to set

```
set @@global.log_table = 'TABLE';
```

Comment: In your favourite MySQL client. The console (`mysql`), PHPMyAdmin, MySQL Workbench, MySQL Query Browser, Toad, ...